# PHPCR ODM - get path of not-persisted document

Tags: symfony, doctrine, jcr, doctrine-odm, doctrine-phpcr

I'm trying to determine the 'future' path a document will get in Doctrine PHPCR ODM, but I don't know how to do this. I can't find any clear documentation on this either...

Can someone help me out on determining the path a document/node will be stored in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was using the wrong order...

You can find out the path of a document by setting the parent first using Document::setParent() and putting all listeners / validators / whatever after that with Document::getParent()::getId().